# Runtime performance (speed) optimization -- Cache size consideration

Tags: c++, performance, caching

What are the basic tips and tricks that a C++ programmer should know when trying to optimize his code in the context of Caching?

Here's something to think about:

- For instance, I know that reducing a function's footprint would make the code run a bit faster since you would have less overall instructions on the processor's instruction register I.
- When trying to allocate an `std::array<char, <size>>`, what would be the ideal size that could make your read and writes faster to the array?
- How big can an object be to decide to put it on the heap instead of the stack?

Comment: First thing to consider is how to measure WHERE your code is spending its time (from a cpu or response time performance point-of-view). That way, you spend your real life time working on improving things that will have a positive impact on your users.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, knowing the correct answer to your question will gain you less than 1% overall performance.

Some (data-)cache optimizations that come to my mind are:

- For arrays: use less RAM. Try shorter data types or a simple compression algorithm like [RLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding). This can also save CPU at the same time, or in the opposite waste CPU cycles with data type conversions. Especially floating point to integer conversions can be quite expensive.
- Avoid access to the same cacheline (usually around 64 bytes) from different threads, unless all access is read-only.
- Group members that are often used together next to each other. Prefer sequential access to random access.

If you really want to know all about caches, read [What Every Programmer Should Know About Memory](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf). While I disagree with the title, it's a great in-depth document.

Because your question suggests that you actually expect gains from just following the tips above (in which case you will be disappointed), here are some general optimization tips:

Tip #1: About 90% of your code you should be optimized for readability, not performance. If you decide to attempt an optimization for performance, make sure you actually measure the gain. When it is below 5% I usually go back to the more readable version.

Tip #2: If you have an existing codebase, profile it first. If you don't profile it, you will miss some very effective optimizations. Usually there are some calls to time-consuming functions that can be completely eliminated, or the result cached.

If you don't want to use a profiler, at least print the current time in a couple of places, or interrupt the program with a debugger a couple of times to check where it is most often spending its time.